# how to generate bitcoin adddres using seed?

Tags: blockchain, bitcore, bitcoinjs

Hi i am new to bitcoin all i want to know is how to generate address using mnemonic seed?

```
let testnet =Bitcoin.networks.testnet;
let keypair =Bitcoin.ECPair.makeRandom({network:testnet});
let address=keypair.getAddress();
let privateKey=keypair.toWIF();
res.json("Public Address  "+ address+ "  "+privateKey)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [bitcoinjs-lib](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib) and [bip39](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bip39). You can install those with `npm install bitcoinjs-lib bip39 --save`

```
const Bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
const Bip39 = require('bip39');
const Bip32 = require('bip32');

function getAddress (node, network) {
  return Bitcoin.payments.p2pkh({ pubkey: node.publicKey, network }).address
}

const mnemonic = `entire taste skull already invest view turtle surge razor key next \
buffalo venue canoe sheriff winner wash ten subject hamster scrap unit shield garden`;

const seed = Bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic);

const root = Bip32.fromSeed(seed, Bitcoin.networks.bitcoin);

const child1 = root.derivePath("m/44'/0'/0'/0/0");
const child2 = root.deriveHardened(44).deriveHardened(0).deriveHardened(0).derive(0).derive(0);

console.log(getAddress(child1)); //1ENQm8nEP7sd6dqXbAMYZ4AuqcP8Y7AtR
console.log(getAddress(child2)); //1Hb6Z1uZ1RuZ6GXTvedQ2ETYKYsMc5qynN
```

You can check the code is working using [this website](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/). You might also want to read up a little about BIP32, BIP39 and BIP44. An executive summary below:

- The BIP32 describes how you can generate new child keys programmatically from a single key and a few other properties.
- BIP39 defines a set of standard words used to mimic a key and how to transform them back to the original "seed" (the key from BIP32).
- BIP44 specifies how you should compute the child keys from the parent one. You can see from my code that I used `derivePath("m/44'/0'/0'/0/0");` in conformance of its specification.

Comment: Does the GUI have a way?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the complete code to run everything from your browser:

```
#!/bin/bash 
#
# call this {anything}.sh
# when finished, run chmod +x *.sh
# then ./*.sh should execute the script 
#
# Create a ECDSA keypair for use with crypto currencies
# The key will be derived from whatever seed phrase is entered by the user
#
# Copyright (c) 2019 B Tasker

read -p "Enter a seed sentence: " seedphrase

# Derive a private key
privkey=$(echo "$seedphrase" | openssl sha256 | cut -d\  -f2)

# Get a proper copy of the private key
privkeyfull=$(openssl ec -inform DER -in <(cat <(echo -n "302e0201010420") <(echo -n "$privkey") <(echo -n "a00706052b8104000a") | xxd -r -p) 2>/dev/null)

# Now start creating the pub key 
longpub=$(openssl ec -inform DER -text -noout -in <(cat <(echo -n "302e0201010420") <(echo -n "$privkey") <(echo -n "a00706052b8104000a") | xxd -r -p) 2>/dev/null  | tail -6 | head -5 | sed 's/[ :]//g' | tr -d '\n' && echo)

# Create the compressed version
compub=$(echo -n "$longpub" | cut -c1-66 | sed 's/^04/02/')

# Now RipeMD it:
hash256=$(echo "$compub" | xxd -r -p | openssl sha256 | cut -d\  -f2)
ripemd=$(echo "$hash256" | xxd -r -p | openssl ripemd160 | cut -d\  -f2)

# Now RipeMD the uncompressed :
hash256=$(echo "$longpub" | xxd -r -p | openssl sha256 | cut -d\  -f2)
ripemdunc=$(echo "$hash256" | xxd -r -p | openssl ripemd160 | cut -d\  -f2)

# And a version we can pass into OpenSSL if we need to
pubkeyfull=$(openssl ec -inform DER -in <(cat <(echo -n "302e0201010420") <(echo -n "e359ae12b3c49fa0d59d0947a97acc9d8595017205909a883501ae09d4ea1888") <(echo -n "a00706052b8104000a") | xxd -r -p) -pubout 2>/dev/null)

cat << EOM
Seed Phrase: 
$seedphrase

Keys:

Private: $privkey
Long public: $longpub
Compressed Public: $compub
RipeMD (Compressed) Public: $ripemd
RipeMD (Uncompressed) Public: $ripemdunc

PEMs:

$privkeyfull
$pubkeyfull

Keep these safe
EOM
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler than you think using command lines. Look at https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-system/wiki/Altcoin-Version-Mappings#7-bitcoin-btc-bip-3944-technology-examples.